# AudioServicesPlaySystemSound not working in iOS8

Tags: audio, ios8

I've had this code in my apps since iOS3 and it has been working. As far I know, these libraries didn't get changed at all in iOS8, but it's not working in iOS8. It doesn't crash or anything, it just never plays the sound effect.

Any ideas?

```
static void completionCallback (SystemSoundID  mySSID, void* myself) {
    AudioServicesRemoveSystemSoundCompletion(mySSID);
    AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(mySSID);
}

+ (void) playSound: (NSString *)path {
    SystemSoundID soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path], &soundID);    
    AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion(soundID, NULL, NULL, completionCallback, NULL);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem with my app, the code, like yours, was running fine until iOS 8. I have noticed that if you tap one of the volume keys while the sound is meant to be playing you can then hear the sound. It's like the sound is playing but with no volume. these were my findings while testing on an iPhone 5c. The same code works just fine on my iPad Air. Mmmm.

Comment: have you found any solution?

Answer (score 9):

I have found the answer to mine problem, it may fix yours. I went into the settings and changed the volume of the Ringer and Alerts, this was on the Sounds section. Mine was set to nil for some reason. I did not realise that AudioServices were connect to this sound level. For my needs I'm probably going to switch to using AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: I tried this on my simulator and my device and it did not change anything for me.

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue on iOS 9.2 in 2016. It would be nice to find resolution for this to avoid using the heavier AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: It worked for me I just changed the slider in sound setting.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a bit old post. But I encountered this issue recently and this is my solution to the issue.

Go to `settings`>`sounds`>`Ringer and alerts`. Increase the volume and try to play the sound.Most probably this will work.

***Also the code that you are using will get deprecated soon.Use the following.***

```
+(void)playClickSound
{
    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"click_sound.mp3" withExtension:nil]; //filename can include extension e.g. @"bang.wav"
    if (fileURL)
    {
        SystemSoundID theSoundID;
        OSStatus error = AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)fileURL, &theSoundID);
        if (error == kAudioServicesNoError)
        {
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithCompletion(theSoundID, ^{
                AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(theSoundID);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the sound was turned up ok... but the ipad was on Mute. Swipe up from bottom (control center) and unmute

Answer (score 1):

For me it was the ring/silent switch that was flipped (the switch above the up/down volume buttons). SpriteKit sounds still worked perfectly fine, so this behavior is quite annoying.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. It was working fine at one point but had stopped working later on.

I checked the code over and over and I Googled my issue to see if I could find any clues.

It turned out that simply turning the device off and then back on again solved the issue!